# C Program bump into segmentation fault. (gdb) Cannot access memory at address

Tags: arrays, c, vector, segmentation-fault, function-definition

I am trying to write codes in C for dynamic array (vector), and it runs okay until I add another function pointer into the struct **(line29: int (*findEle)(vector*, int) )**, and initialize it **(line 153: v->findEle = findEle)** to point to the function implementation (line 125: int findEle(vector* v, int value)). The debugger starts returning segmentation fault every time I tried to run it. Please find the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int BOOL;
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0


typedef struct Vector vector;

struct Vector
{
    int currCapacity;
    int currSize;
    int *items;
    // TODO: Try to add another int field, will cause seg fault

    int (*size)(vector*);
    int (*capacity)(vector*);
    BOOL (*is_empty)(vector*);
    void *(*at)(vector*, int);
    void (*push)(vector*, int);
    void (*insert)(vector*, int, int);
    void (*resize)(vector*, size_t);
    int (*pop)(vector*);
    void (*removeValue)(vector*, int);
    void (*delete_ele)(vector*, int);
    int (*findEle)(vector*, int);
};


// Vector Functions
int size(vector *v)
{
    return v->currSize;
}

int capacity(vector *v)
{
    return v->currCapacity;
}

BOOL is_empty(vector *v)
{
    if(v->currSize==0){ return TRUE; }
    return FALSE;
}

void *at(vector *v, int index)
{
    if(index >= v->currSize){return NULL;}
    return (int*)(v->items+index);
}

void push(vector *v, int item)
{
    if(v->currSize == v->currCapacity)
    {
        v->items = (int*)realloc(v->items, sizeof(int)* (v->currCapacity * 2));
        v->currCapacity = v->currCapacity * 2;
    }
    *(v->items+v->currSize) = item;
    v->currSize++;
}

void insert(vector* v, int index, int item)
{
    printf("Inserting %d at index %d\n", item, index);
    if(v->currSize == v->currCapacity)
    {
        v->items = (int*)realloc(v->items, sizeof(int)* (v->currCapacity * 2));
        printf("v->items address: %p\n", v->items);
        v->currCapacity = v->currCapacity * 2;
    }
    int* shift_ptr = v->items+index;
    memmove(v->items+index+1, v->items+index, sizeof(int)*(v->currSize-index));
    *(v->items+index) = item;   
    v->currSize++;
}

void resize(vector* v, size_t size)
{
    printf("Resizing from %d to %d\n", v->currSize, size);
    v->items = (int*)realloc(v->items, sizeof(int)* size);
}

int pop(vector* v)
{
    int last = *(v->items + (v->currSize-1));
    v->currSize--;
    if(v->currSize*4 == v->currCapacity)
    {
        v->resize(v, v->currCapacity/2);
    }
    return last;
}

void delete_ele(vector* v, int index)
{
    int *curr_ptr = v->items+index;
    if(v->currSize*4 == v->currCapacity)
    {
        v->resize(v, v->currCapacity/2);
    }
    memmove(curr_ptr, curr_ptr+1, sizeof(int)*(v->currSize-(index+1)));
    v->currSize--;
}

void removeValue(vector *v, int value)
{
    for(int i=0; i<v->currSize; i++)
    {
        int ptr_value = *(v->items+i);
        printf("%d->%d ", i, ptr_value);
        if(ptr_value==value)
        {
            delete_ele(v, i);
            --i;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int findEle(vector* v, int value)
{
    for(int i=0; i<v->currSize; i++)
    {
        if(*(v->items+i)==value)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

vector *initializeVector()
{
    vector *v;
    v->currSize = 0;
    v->currCapacity = 2;
    v->items = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * v->currCapacity);

    v->size = size;
    v->capacity = capacity;
    v->is_empty = is_empty;
    v->at = at;
    v->push = push;
    v->insert = insert;
    v->pop = pop;
    v->removeValue = removeValue;
    v->delete_ele = delete_ele;
    v->findEle = findEle;
    return v;
}


int main()
{
    vector *v = initializeVector();
    v->push(v, 8);
    v->push(v, 25);
    v->push(v, 25);
    v->push(v, 12);
    printf("element 0 :%d\n", *(int*)v->at(v, 0));
    printf("element 1 :%d\n", *(int*)v->at(v, 1));
    printf("element 2 :%d\n", *(int*)v->at(v, 2));
    printf("element 3 :%d\n", *(int*)v->at(v, 3));
    v->insert(v, 1, 50);
    printf("element 0 :%d\n", *(int*)v->at(v, 0));
    printf("element 1 :%d\n", *(int*)v->at(v, 1));
    printf("element 2 :%d\n", *(int*)v->at(v, 2));
    printf("element 3 :%d\n", *(int*)v->at(v, 3));
    printf("element 4 :%d\n", *(int*)v->at(v, 4));
    //printf("%d\n", v->pop(v));
    printf("%d\n", v->findEle(v, 25));
    v->removeValue(v, 25);
    for(int i=0; i<v->currSize; i++)
    {
        int ptr_value = *(v->items+i);
        printf("%d->%d ", i, ptr_value);
    }
    free(v->items);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to debug using gdb, it returns the below message:

*Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0040189a in initializeVector () at Vector.c:153
153         v->findEle = findEle;*

When I tried to get the address of the stated function, it showed the message below:
*(gdb) x v->findEle
Cannot access memory at address 0x620000*

Can someone kindly advice if I have some issues on memory allocation? Or the issue might be due to some other causes? Thanks!

Comment: `vector *v` is uninitialized, it's not pointing to anything useful, so you're invoking undefined behaviour. You need to `malloc` memory for the struct itself, and appropriately free it as needed.

Comment: Hi @ThomasJager, thanks a lot for your pointer. I did malloc to the struct during the initialization stage : vector *v = (vector *)malloc(sizeof(vector)); and it solved the issue :) I have a clarification question, since I am invoking undefined behavior previously, is it correct to say that it is only a matter of time that I bump into this issue?

Comment: You *might* not necessarily ever notice it, but you probably would. Undefined behaviour really means that, it's undefined. Anything could happen, from it working correctly (unlikely) to crashing or otherwise giving incorrect results (most likely, and what you see here, actual likely effect will depend on what's causing the UB) to your program saying mean things to you (extremely unlikely ;) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in these functions

```
void resize(vector* v, size_t size)
{
    printf("Resizing from %d to %d\n", v->currSize, size);
    v->items = (int*)realloc(v->items, sizeof(int)* size);
}

int pop(vector* v)
{
    int last = *(v->items + (v->currSize-1));
    v->currSize--;
    if(v->currSize*4 == v->currCapacity)
    {
        v->resize(v, v->currCapacity/2);
    }
    return last;
}

void delete_ele(vector* v, int index)
{
    int *curr_ptr = v->items+index;
    if(v->currSize*4 == v->currCapacity)
    {
        v->resize(v, v->currCapacity/2);
    }
    memmove(curr_ptr, curr_ptr+1, sizeof(int)*(v->currSize-(index+1)));
    v->currSize--;
}
```

you do not update data members `currCapacity` and `currSize`

And in this function

```
vector *initializeVector()
{
    vector *v;
    v->currSize = 0;
    v->currCapacity = 2;
    v->items = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * v->currCapacity);

    v->size = size;
    v->capacity = capacity;
    v->is_empty = is_empty;
    v->at = at;
    v->push = push;
    v->insert = insert;
    v->pop = pop;
    v->removeValue = removeValue;
    v->delete_ele = delete_ele;
    v->findEle = findEle;
    return v;
}
```

there is used the uninitialized pointer `v` that has an indeterminate value that results in undefined behavior.

Also you need to check the value of the parameter `index` in each function where it is used.

Comment: Thanks @Vlad from Moscow ! I think I should’ve update the currSize and currCapacity correctly when doing the resize. I did the fix on the uninitialised pointer, and it solved the issue on seg fault. :)